# group by unix timestamp + by 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a reporting program which is using MySQL as a database and php as scripting language.

What i'm trying to do is to group records by time and group them in hours having last 24 hours in the result set.

**Current Query**

```
SELECT count(*),time FROM `service_data` GROUP BY time
```

the query above does not group them by last 24 hours it just groups similar unixtimestamp together

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

In the result set i want 24 records null if no reports in a particular hour.

**Like so**

```
| hour |  reports |
|------|----------|
|   1  |    5     |
|   2  |    10    |
|   3  |    12    |
|   4  |    25    |
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: why is time stored at an `int` and not a `timestamp`?

Comment: because im using php to insert timestamp just for the heck of it.

Comment: is time current unix timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last 24 hours, convert the time of 1 day ago to a unix timestamp:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

To convert a timestamp back to an hour, first convert it to a time, then use the `HOUR` function:

```
HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))
```

Combining these, you can do:

```
SELECT HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) AS hour, COUNT(*)
FROM service_data
WHERE time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY hour
```

If the table is very large, add an index on the `time` column so this will not have to do a full scan.

To get results for hours that have no data, you'll need to use a `LEFT JOIN` with a table that contains all the hour numbers:

```
SELECT t1.hour, COUNT(s.id) AS reports
FROM (SELECT 0 AS hour UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 ... UNION SELECT 23) AS t1
LEFT JOIN service_data AS s
ON t1.hour = HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(s.time)) AND s.time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY t1.hour
ORDER BY t1.hour
```

Comment: 1 day = 24 hours not always.

Comment: When is a day not 24 hours?

Comment: @Barmar when switching from daylight savings and back. Once a year a day is 23 hours long and once it's 25 hours long.

Comment: **"In the result set i want 24 records null if no reports in a particular hour."**

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I've added code to deal with missing hours.

Comment: @apokryfos I'm not sure how to make this do the right thing when DST changes. It's not even clear what the right thing is -- how should the extra hour when the clock goes back be counted?

Comment: @apokryfos, how that can be manipulate in a SQL Query? There's no way  AFAIK.

Comment: its good enough i think, i appreciate it, i was able to use php to fill the hours that had no results.

Comment: @Barmar if you do `INTERVAL 1 DAY` then it goes to the same time one day in the future/past, which mostly 24 hours but not always. The OP mentioned "last 24 hours" possibly with the idea that it always means a day, so what you wrote is what the OP really wanted. However if the 24 hours was a very strict requirement then `INTERVAL 24 HOUR` would have probably been better.

Comment: is there a way to show only up to the current hour and not the last 24 hour result too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. But you can certainly put any criteria on `s.time` in the `ON` clause, to filter out times you don't want.